# Checking for a transaction on a large number of bsc addresses

Tags: transactions, addresses, bsc, binance-smart-chain

I need to frequently check a large number of addresses for transactions on the bsc network (at least a thousand per second), what is the best way to do this? The only solution I know of is to run my own node, but this method takes a lot of resources and time to synchronize. What are some alternative methods?

Comment: I would say for this amount of queries, it's better and cheaper to build and run own node. There is some Service providers which can make this job for you, but the cost will be much more than just spending 200 bucks for building a raspy node. It takes about 5 to 7 days to sync.

Comment: You have to run your own node. I'm not sure raspberry pi is fast enough. @Akall you need some significant power to run a BSC node; you need at least a 2TB NVMe SSD which is $200 by itself (anything other than NVMe is too slow) and a fast Intel or AMD CPU (faster the better for syncing, but I'd guess that a dual-core i3 is probably enough) and 16GB of RAM. You basically do want to dedicate a whole computer to it, if possible.

Comment: @Akall, does a full node synchronization really take so little time? I thought it would take weeks to fully synchronize a bsc node.

Comment: @Cosmo773 excuse me and my stupidness, i've though i am speaking about BTC node. For BSC what i can suggest is a small portable computer, intel NUC for example, but it will be more expensive than the raspberry for sure. However i still believe it will be a cheaper option if you need to monitor for long time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any alternative method. You have to run your own node, or leech off someone else's node, and nobody is going to let you do this on their node.

If you were okay with only checking each address once a day or so, you could ask some public node, but you will certainly be banned if you make a thousand requests every second.

Note there is no point in querying more often than once per block, which is every 3 seconds.